# Scientifc Notation Java

Tags: java, decimal, scientific-notation

I am working on a problem which was given to me by my friend. I need to take the input number in the form `x.yzw*10^p` where `p` is non zero and `x.yzw` can be zeros. I have made the program but the problem is that when we have numbers such as `0.098`, decimal format will make it `9.8` but I need to get it to be `9.800`, it has to always be outputted as `x.yzw*10^p`. can someone please show me how this is possible.

```
input:    output:
1234.56   1.235 x 10^3
1.2       1.200
0.098     9.800 x 10^-2
```

Code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.math.RoundingMode;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ConvertScientificNotation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
        double input = sc.nextDouble();
        StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(Double.toString(input));

        sBuffer.append("00");
        System.out.println(sBuffer.toString());
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(df.format(Double.parseDouble(sBuffer.toString())));

        if (sb.charAt(sb.length()-1) == '0') {
            System.out.println(sBuffer.toString());
        } else {
            sb.replace(sb.indexOf("E"), sb.indexOf("E")+1, "10^");
            sb.insert(sb.indexOf("10"), " x ");
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest starting by looking at [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html); it should do most of what you're looking for relatively easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(".000");
String output = myFormatter.format(input)
```

then if you want to convert 'output' into a number, use:

```
Float answer = Float.parseFloat(output)
```

**EDIT**

also check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) out, it contains more information on how to format numbers

Comment: but If I do this then It won't convert it to scientific form.. how can I make it so it does both?

Comment: @user: Out of curiousity/posterity, how *did* you get it to do both?

Comment: I just did DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000E0"); It seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);

String formatted = df.format(0.098); //"9.8E-2"
```

Then you can just do a search and replace for E:

```
String replaced = formatted.replaceAll("E", " x 10^");
```

Answer (score 0):

make your format string ".000" and it will not drop 'empty' zeroes from your formatted number.